Are translations of Kant problematic because they lose conceptual precision?
How good are the translations of Kant in various languages? What are the experiences of those who have read Kant in languages other than German, but are native German speakers and have studied Kant extensively? Is there a loss of conceptual precision? If so, do you have specific examples where this becomes evident?
